# Clarification around Spring-AOP pointcuts and inheritance

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

Given the following example classes in `my.package`...

```
public class Foo {
    public void logicNotInBar()     {/*code*/}
    public void logicBarOverrides() {/*code*/}
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    public void logicBarOverrides() {/*code*/}
}
```

and the following Spring-AOP pointcuts...

```
<aop:pointcut id="myPointcutAll" expression="execution(* my.package.*.*(..))"   />
<aop:pointcut id="myPointcutFoo" expression="execution(* my.package.Foo.*(..))" />
<aop:pointcut id="myPointcutBar" expression="execution(* my.package.Bar.*(..))" />
```

What is the result of advice applied to the above pointcuts on instances of Bar? In particular...

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.logicNotInBar();      // will myPointcutBar advice trigger?
bar.logicBarOverrides();  // is myPointcutFoo ignored here?
```

I think I am missing some basic truth of how pointcuts interact with inheritance so an under-the-hood explanation/doc would probably go a long way.

Comment: No advice will be applied because Bar is not a "Proxy Bean", you can't manually instantiate a class that has to be advised... it has to be defined as Spring Bean: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch08s06.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies

Comment: and also it's good to use interfaces, and define Pointcuts on those interfaces rather then on implementations: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch08.html#aop-introduction-proxies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [aspectj documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html):

> When matching method-execution join points, if the execution pointcut
>   method signature specifies a declaring type, the pointcut will only
>   match methods declared in that type, or methods that override methods
>   declared in or inherited by that type. So the pointcut
>
> **execution(public void Middle.*())**
>
> picks out all method executions
>   for public methods returning void and having no arguments that are
>   either declared in, or inherited by, Middle, even if those methods are
>   overridden in a subclass of Middle. So the pointcut would pick out the
>   method-execution join point for Sub.m() in this code:

```
  class Super {
    protected void m() { ... }
  }
  class Middle extends Super {
  }
  class Sub extends Middle {
    public void m() { ... }
  }
```