# AOP - @Pointcut syntax: how define the method with a superclass argument/parameter

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am working with `Spring Framework` and `AspectJ` version `1.8.9`

I have many Service classes, lets consider for example

- CustomerServiceImpl
- InvoiceServiceImpl
- CarServiceImpl

The point is, each one has a `saveOne` method. Therefore

- saveOne(Customer customer)
- saveOne(Invoice invoice)
- saveOne(Car car)

If I use the following:

```
@Pointcut(value="execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.impl.*ServiceImpl.saveOne(Car, ..)) && args(entity) && target(object)")
public void saveOnePointcut(Car entity, Object object){}

@Before(value="ServicePointcut.saveOnePointcut(entity, object)")
public void beforeAdviceSaveOne(Car entity, Object object){
```

It works. Until here for a better understanding:

- The first parameter represents the Entity (`Car` in this case) to persist
- The second parameter represents the Object or target (XServiceImpl) has been 'intercepted'

**Note**: I need the first parameter for audit and logging purposes. Therefore it is mandatory.

To avoid do verbose and create more for each entity, I want use a 'superclass' type. I've tried with

```
@Pointcut(value="execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.impl.*ServiceImpl.saveOne(Object, ..)) && args(entity) && target(object)")
public void saveOnePointcut(Object entity, Object object){}

@Before(value="ServicePointcut.saveOnePointcut(entity, object)")
public void beforeAdviceSaveOne(Object entity, Object object){
```

Observe the first parameter now is an `Object` And it does not work.

If is possible accomplish this requirement, what is the correct syntax?

I've read [Clarification around Spring-AOP pointcuts and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727454/clarification-around-spring-aop-pointcuts-and-inheritance) but it is about only for methods *without* parameter(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `Object+` instead of just `Object`. `+` means all classes that extend target class. So your aspect code will look like this:

```
@Pointcut(value="execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.impl.*ServiceImpl.saveOne(Object+, ..)) && args(entity) && target(object)")
public void saveOnePointcut(Object entity, Object object){}

@Before(value="ServicePointcut.saveOnePointcut(entity, object)")
public void beforeAdviceSaveOne(Object entity, Object object){
```

I tried this with my code samples and it's work fine for all type of arguments.

Comment: Thank you!, it works fine. Normally I have seen that `+` in the Interface/Class declaration within the Pointcut, never in the parameter.

Comment: Why not just use `*` instead of `Object+`? It is basically equivalent, less verbose and easier to understand. The `MyClass+` syntax should only be used if you have a specific base class other than `Object` in mind.

Comment: @kriegaex you are right `*` is better then `Object+`, but i make some research and can say that all of this makes no sense for AspectJ in case of `args(entity)` and seems that the best way is `execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.impl.*ServiceImpl.saveOne(..)) && args(entity) && target(object)`

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Why does it make no sense? It works as I suggested. What kind of research told you otherwise?

Comment: Sorry if i my comment confused you. I just wanted to say that ‘execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.impl.*ServiceImpl.saveOne(Object+, ..)) && args(entity)‘ and ‘execution(* com.manuel.jordan.service.impl.*ServiceImpl.saveOne(..)) && args(entity)‘ produce same result, so first variant is overabundant

Comment: I respect both opinions, but for `AOP` I don't like use a lot wildcards. I keep the idea that when times passes and I return to some `@Pointcut` I want re understand the idea very quickly. Therefore for this scenario I prefer the idea about use `saveOne(Object+, ..))` than `saveOne(..))` or `saveOne(*))`

Comment: @SergeyBespalov sorry to bother you, perhaps you can help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821938/spring-aop-how-exclude-an-unnecessary-pointcut-around-advice-execution-due thanks

Comment: Hi, @ManuelJordan. I think that i can help but need to check the answer first. I can do it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @SergeyBespalov don't worry, seems I have a possible solution. Testing right now. Thanks a lot again by your support. Best Regards!